# How to add a background logo to every word document in MS Word 2010

Tags: ms-word, background-image

This isn't really a programming question, but I think it could nonetheless be a useful piece of information :)

I would want to add a background logo to every page of my word document so that it doesn't take up any space (meaning text and other pictures can overlap it if needed).

How would you do this in MS Word 2010? I can add a single picture behind text etc. but if I had 200 pages how could I do it so that MS Word would automatically add this picture to every page and at the exact same spot?

here is a picture highlighting my question:

[image]

Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add backgroung image to word document, then go for watermark option. which is under design tab. 
Hope this will help.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your help. I found the watermark option under "Page Layout" in Word 2010. Page Layout --> Watermark --> Custom watermark. For moving the watermark to desired position I opened the header and footer tools and simply dragged the watermark to desired position :)